# Conversión de Varchar a Date MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estimadxs, tengan buenas tardes, se que han hecho esta pregunta muchas veces pero las respuestas que hay no solucionan mi inconveniente. Tengo una tabla en una `*BD*` de `MSSQL` llamada **TablaA**, en la misma se registran los datos de las personas incluída su fecha de nacimiento. El problema radica en ese punto. El tipo de dato para almacenar la información de la fecha es tipo `NVARCHAR(10)`. Asumiendo que quizá, tal vez en su prehistórico momento se pensó que quienes cargarían la fecha lo harían con el siguiente formato: **dd/MM/yyyy**. Pero, eso no pasó. Primero porque se permitió almacenar **nulos**, segundo porque quienes fueron cargado la información lo hicieron tanto como **dd/MM/yy** como **dd/MM/yyyy**. Para ponerlos en un contexto descriptivo, muestro lo siguiente:

```
PERSONA FECHANAC
JUAN P  NULL
PEPITO  12/12/00
PEPITA  01/03/1978
```

Así que quisiera consultar si hay alguna forma de hacer una conversión para que todas las **FECHANAC** tengan un mismo formato a través de un `SELECT`. Lo que pensé fue que, a partir de la cantidad de caracteres que posee el valor almacenado, si el valor tiene una longitud de **8 (ocho) caracteres (dd/MM/yy)** este tome el formato de **dd/MM/yyyy** para ello hice lo siguiente:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(FECHANAC) = 8
    THEN CONVERT(DATE, FECHANAC, 103)
    ELSE CONVERT(DATE, FECHANAC, 103)
    END AS Fecha
FROM TablaA
WHERE FECHANAC IS NOT NULL
```

Pero me sale el bendito error:

```
Error al convertir una cadena de caracteres en fecha y/u hora.
```

¿Alguna solución posible? Desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo.

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Después de haber hecho un par de correciones, existen dos inconvenientes. Primero adjunto como ha quedado la consulta a partir de las modificaciones:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN LEN(affenacli) = 8
        THEN CONVERT(DATE, affenacli, 3)
        ELSE ISNULL(affenacli, CONVERT(DATE, '01/01/1900', 103))
    END AS Fecha
FROM Cliente 
    INNER JOIN Sorteados
        ON Cliente.andnicli = Sorteados.DNI
WHERE affenacli IS NOT NULL
```

Esto me muestra un formato y valores, con respecto al año, fuera de lugar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo se ve en la imagen, el formato que me devuelve es yyyy-MM-dd y años cómo 2034/2032 cosa que no debería suceder. ¿Alguien sabe porqué?

Comment: en un mismo campo, tu select esta guardando ahora datos de tipo date (los convertidos) y datos sin convertir (de tipo varchar)... o yo veo mal?otra cosa, la base de datos es sql server? porque etiquetaste sql (generico) y luego mssql (un driver, no una db)

Comment: Si, si, ya corregí tanto el select como los tags. Gracia spor notarlo  @gbianchi

Comment: los dos no pueden tener el formato 103 ;)... el otro no es 11?

Comment: El 11 es yy/mm/dd y yo quiero que todos tengan el formato dd/mm/yyyy @gbianchi

Comment: claro.. pero al convert, vos le decis en que formato viene ;) al pasarlo a fecha, todos van a estar completitos... no?

Comment: es mas.. los null, tambien deberias tenerlos en cuenta, o saltearlos.. como sabe convert a que convertir un null?

Comment: Gracias a ti, el formato correcto es 3. Pero, al usar DATE la fecha se muestra domo yyyy-MM-dd y me muestra años como 2032/2034/2040 @gbianchi

Comment: y eso es un tema.. la db no sabe que si le pasas 30 lo tiene que convertir a 1930 ;)... ahi me parece que requeris ya de otra logica un poquito mas propia.. mira la [documentacion](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) que explica justamene eso...

Comment: igual, el formato es particular de la herramienta que estas usando para visualizar... lo podrias mostrar como quieras despues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dejo un ejemplo de como lo puedes hacer. Es importante hacer notar que el hecho de haber guardado las fechas en ese formato se presta a errores en caso de que se hayan guardado con formato de Estados Unidos (mm/dd/yy) o en algo similar al formato ISO corto (yy/mm/dd). En caso de que existan esos casos, puedes obtener un valor erróneo o nulos.

```
WITH CTE( PERSONA, FECHANAC) AS(
    SELECT 'JUAN P',  NULL         UNION ALL
    SELECT 'PEPITO',  '12/12/00'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'PEPITA',  '01/03/1978' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ROSITA',  '01/03/18'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GLORIA',  '01/03/38'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'JAIME ',  '01/30/18' 
 )
 SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN LEN( FECHANAC) = 8 AND TRY_CONVERT( DATE, FECHANAC, 3) > GETDATE()
            THEN DATEADD( YY, -100, TRY_CONVERT( DATE, FECHANAC, 3))
         WHEN LEN( FECHANAC) = 8 
            THEN TRY_CONVERT( DATE, FECHANAC, 3)
        ELSE TRY_CONVERT( DATE, FECHANAC, 103) END
 FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución temporal fue crear una tabla temporal

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
id INT IDENTITY, 
fecha SMALLDATETIME, 
titulo INT, 
sexo NVARCHAR(1))
```

A partir de ahí insertar los datos pertinentes que necesito:

```
INSERT INTO  #temp (fecha, titulo, sexo)
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(affenacli) >= YEAR(GETDATE())
            THEN DATEADD(YYYY, -100, affenacli) 
            ELSE affenacli
            END AS Fecha, 
            TITULO, 
            Sexo
FROM Cliente 
    INNER JOIN Sorteados
        ON Cliente.andnicli = Sorteados.DNI
WHERE affenacli IS NOT NULL
```